# How could I call Java code dynamically?

Tags: java, dynamic, eval

How could I write Java code that is executed like javascript code used together with the eval function?

What I would like to achieve would be something like this:

System.execute ("String str = \"test\"; System.out.println(str);");

which would print the word 'test'. (10x  dehmann )

A code sample would help a lot.

Comment: It might just be me, but your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  JavaScript is a Web Scripting language, where as java is run in the java framework.  You can build java applets, but I don't think that's what you're referring to.

Comment: I'm guessing the reference to JavaScript was just an example of what he wants to achieve.

Comment: I think he wants something like: System.execute("String str(\"test\"); System.out.println(str);"); which would print the word 'test'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an eval() function in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Look into BeanShell or Groovy.  Both will give you reasonable solutions--but those solutions rely on my interpretation of your problem, which may be flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the JavaScript engine shipped with Java 6 and it works quite well. The performance of the engine is very very decent.

Check the page http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe the compiler API is present in the current Java SE 6. See the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html).

See [this blog post](http://www.juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/12/13/java-se-6-compiler-api/) for details and an example.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, the Compiler API is coming in the next version of Java..

Comment: The Compiler API is in Java 6. It works but its ugly to use. However you can use BeanShell and JCI if you don't have Java 6.