# Is there an eval() function in Java?

Tags: java, eval

I have a string like the following:

```
String str = "4*5";
```

Now I have to get the result of `20` by using the string.

I know in some other languages the `eval()` function will do this.
How can I do this in Java?

Comment: I'd suggest forgetting about Java for this task and use Clojure. Clojure allows you to parse and/or compile code at runtime (and at compile time) and run it, and also to generate code at compile time as well as many other things which are, by the way, pretty usual in the LISP world. Java is too boring. And Clojure can do everything that Java can, because it runs on JVM (although other implementations do exist, too)
And it can be mixed with Java seamlessly, even inside one shared project.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of a question asking [how to evaluate an arithmetic expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) because it _specifically_ asks about eval().

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can use the [`ScriptEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) class and evaluate it as a Javascript string.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval("4*5");
```

There may be a better way, but this one works.

Comment: Loading an entire JavaScript interpreter to do some math seems like a huge waste. But you're right, it works, especially if efficiency isn't a priority.

Comment: In addition to being a bit of overkill, using the JavaScript interpreter opens you up to code injection. If you do not tightly control the expression, someone could send you `while(true){ 3+4;}` and hang your JVM.

Comment: It is efficient in terms of coding time.  If you use it all of the time, you could consider keeping it around in memory, perhaps in a singleton object.

Comment: This is how I imported it into my build.gradle: `testCompile group: 'org.apache.bsf', name: 'bsf-all', version: '3.0-beta3'`. [Source](http://www.1maven.com//classname-packaging?pk=javax.script&cl=ScriptEngineManager)

Comment: How do I import the Script Engine? doing import javax.script.* doesn't apparently include the Script Engine, I get it as "unresolved identifier".

Comment: @nicael See [Reference javax.script.ScriptEngine in android or evaluate a javascript expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454425/reference-javax-script-scriptengine-in-android-or-evaluate-a-javascript-expressi)

Comment: It's always exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

Comment: be sure to add `throws exception` in the function before using that .

Comment: I know I shouldn't use the comments section to say thanks, but I have to say that this has helped me GREATLY. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any alternative after the Engine has been [removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372), please?

Answer (score 55):

There is no standard Java class or method that will do what you want.  Your options include:

- Select and use some third-party expression evaluation library.  For example [JEL](http://www.gnu.org/software/jel/) or any of the half dozen libraries listed [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/expression-languages).
- Wrap the expression in the Java source code for a class with an `eval` method, send that to the Java compiler, and then load the resulting compiled class.
- Use some scripting language that can be called from Java as an expression evaluator.  Possibilities include Javascript<sup>1</sup>, BeanShell, and so on.  A JSR 223 compliant scripting language implementation can be called via the [Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html).
- Write your own expression evaluator from scratch.

The first approach is probably simplest.  The second and third approaches are a potential security risk if you get the expression to be evaluated from an untrusted user.  (Think code injection.)

---

<sup>1 - Javascript in Java SE is a moving target.  From Java 6, a version of Mozilla's Rhino Javascript implementation was bundled with Java SE.  The in Java 8, it was superseded by Nashorn.  In Java 11, Nashorn was deprecated, and finally dropped from the core codebase.  As of 2021, both Rhino and Nashorn are being maintained as separate (non-Oracle) products, and Oracle's GraalVM has its own Javascript implementation.</sup>

Answer (score 36):

There are very few real use cases in which being able to evaluate a `String` as a fragment of Java code is necessary or desirable. That is, asking how to do this is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you actually have a different problem, which can be solved a different way.

First ask yourself, where did this `String` that you wish to evaluate come from? Did another part of your program generate it, or was it input provided by the user?

- **Another part of my program generated it**: so, you want one part of your program to decide the kind of operation to perform,  but not perform the operation, and a second part that performs the chosen operation. Instead of generating and then evaluating  a `String`, use the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) or [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design pattern, as appropriate for your particular case.
- **It is user input**: the user could input *anything*, including commands that, when executed, could cause your program to misbehave, crash, expose information that should be secret, damage persistent information (such as the content of a database), and other such nastiness.  The only way to prevent that would be to parse the `String` yourself,  check it was not malicious, and then evaluate it. But parsing it yourself is much of the work that the requested `eval`function would do, so you have saved yourself nothing. Worse still, checking that arbitrary `Java` was not malicious is *impossible*, because checking that is the [*halting problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).
- **It is user input, but the syntax and semantics of permitted text to evaluate is greatly restricted**: No general purpose facility can easily implement a general purpose parser and evaluator for whatever restricted syntax and semantics you have chosen. What you need to do is implement a parser and evaluator for your chosen syntax and semantics. If the task is simple, you could write a simple [recursive-descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or finite-state-machine parser by hand. If the task is difficult, you could use a [compiler-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) (such as ANTLR) to do some of the work for you.
- **I just want to implement a desktop calculator!**: A homework assignment, eh? If you could implement the evaluation of the input expression using a provided `eval` function, it would not be much of a homework assignment, would it? Your program would be three lines long. Your instructor probably expects you to write the code for a simple arithmetic parser/evaluator. There is well known algorithm, [shunting-yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), which you might find useful.

Comment: What about debugging?

Comment: @Winter - in the real world we use debuggers for that.  In the real world we don't write our own debuggers.  We use debuggers that someone else wrote.  And besides, in a debugger you need to be able to access the values / fields of (typed) variables in the executing program .... which makes it a lot more complicated than "simple" expression parsing / evaluation.

Comment: Asking for an `eval` function in Java is perfectly valid, if you ask yourself if a Java REPL could exist.

Answer (score 23):

With Java 9, we get access to [`jshell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html), so one can write something like this:

```
import jdk.jshell.JShell;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Eval {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(JShell js = JShell.create(); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

            js.onSnippetEvent(snip -> {
                if (snip.status() == jdk.jshell.Snippet.Status.VALID) {
                    System.out.println("➜ " + snip.value());
                }
            });

            System.out.print("> ");
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                js.eval(js.sourceCodeAnalysis().analyzeCompletion(line).source());
                System.out.print("> ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
> 1 + 2 / 4 * 3
➜ 1
> 32 * 121
➜ 3872
> 4 * 5
➜ 20
> 121 * 51
➜ 6171
>
```

Slightly op, but that's what Java currently has to offer

Comment: This would be perfect if my company would allow us to use Java 9 :)

Comment: This is actually a very smart idea. There is no need for extra libs or external dependencies. The only drawback: it is not lightweight in terms of execution speed and memory usage.

Comment: 1 + 2 / 4 * 3 should be 2.5

Comment: @deepakl.2000 That would be `1.0 + 2.0 / 4.0 * 3.0`. Without the decimals, Java treats numbers as integers, and performs integer operations on them; which can only result in integers. For example, while `2/4` is `0.5`, as an integer that value is truncated to `0`. `0*3` is `0`. `0+1` is `1`, hence the output is correct.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma need help for below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666169/javaevaluation-of-mathematical-expression-only-from-left-to-right

Comment: @deepakl.2000 **Ask a new question**, showing what you have so far, what your specific issue is, and what exactly it is that you're trying to do. There's plenty of ways and reasons to parse numeric expressions, and I could help you with that, but often when you end up somewhere like this thread it's a sign of an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @toastrackenigma , the question which I have posted  already has some details , the specific issue and what am trying to achieve.i am still waiting for the complete solution which I have not got. If I raise a new question, it will be marked as duplicate and closed so that is the reason I'm asking for help.hope you understand. Please could you look into it.

Comment: @deepakl.2000 [Let us continue this conversation in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237592/conversation-between-deepakl-2000-toastrackenigma)

Answer (score 14):

I could advise you to use [Exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/). It is easy to understand as you can see from the following example code:

```
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
    .variables("x", "y")
    .build()
    .setVariable("x", 2.3)
    .setVariable("y", 3.14);
double result = e.evaluate();
```

Comment: It looks better than accepted answer in JAVA world.

Comment: But it seems it is not being maintained anymore.

Comment: @wonsuc you are right. I wasn't using it in a while... Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 10):

**No**, you can not have a generic "eval" in Java (or any compiled language). Unless you're willing to write a Java compiler AND a JVM to be executed **inside of your Java program**.

**Yes**, you can have some library to evaluate numeric algebraic expressions like the one above - [see this thread for discussion](http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=784915&tstart=0).

Comment: The link is down.

Comment: Umm...[jshell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 7):

As previous answers, there is no standard API in Java for this.

You can add groovy jar files to your path and groovy.util.Eval.me("4*5") gets your job done.

Comment: Same code injection problems as with using JavaScript though.

Comment: There is. `ScriptEngine`.

Comment: Check the date of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

A fun way to solve your problem could be coding an eval() function on your own!
I've done it for you!

You can use FunctionSolver library simply by typing **FunctionSolver.solveByX(*function*,*value*)** inside your code. The *function* attribute is a String which represents the function you want to solve, the *value* attribute is the value of the independent variable
 of your function (which MUST be x).

If you want to solve a function which contains more than one independent variable, you can use **FunctionSolver.solve(*function*,*values*)** where the *values* attribute is an [HashMap(String,Double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which contains all your independent attributes (as Strings) and their respective values (as Doubles).

Another piece of information: I've coded a simple version of **FunctionSolver**, so its supports only [Math methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) which return a double value and which accepts one or two double values as fields (just use **FunctionSolver.usableMathMethods()** if you're curious) (These methods are: *bs, sin, cos, tan, atan2, sqrt, log, log10, pow, exp, min, max, copySign, signum, IEEEremainder, acos, asin, atan, cbrt, ceil, cosh, expm1, floor, hypot, log1p, nextAfter, nextDown, nextUp, random, rint, sinh, tanh, toDegrees, toRadians, ulp)*. Also, that library supports the following operators: * / + - ^ (even if java normally does not support the ^ operator).

One last thing: while creating this library I had to use [reflections](http://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection) to call [Math methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html). I think it's really cool, just [have a look at this](http://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection) if you are interested in!

That's all, here it is the code (and the [library](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hEjLh_qURwp82P6QZiscCBfil8pVXhA7)):

```
package core;

 import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 public abstract class FunctionSolver {

public static double solveNumericExpression (String expression) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    return solve(expression, new HashMap<>());
}

public static double solveByX (String function, double value) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    HashMap<String, Double> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("x", value);
    return solveComplexFunction(function, function, values);
}

public static double solve (String function, HashMap<String,Double> values) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    return solveComplexFunction(function, function, values);
}

private static double solveComplexFunction (String function, String motherFunction, HashMap<String, Double> values) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    int position = 0;
    while(position < function.length()) {
        if (alphabetic.contains(""+function.charAt(position))) {
            if (position == 0 || !alphabetic.contains(""+function.charAt(position-1))) {
                int endIndex = -1;
                for (int j = position ; j < function.length()-1 ; j++) {
                    if (alphabetic.contains(""+function.charAt(j)) 
                            && !alphabetic.contains(""+function.charAt(j+1))) {
                        endIndex = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (endIndex == -1 & alphabetic.contains(""+function.charAt(function.length()-1))) {
                    endIndex = function.length()-1;
                }
                if (endIndex != -1) {
                    String alphabeticElement = function.substring(position, endIndex+1);
                    if (Arrays.asList(usableMathMethods()).contains(alphabeticElement)) {
                        //Start analyzing a Math function
                        int closeParenthesisIndex = -1;
                        int openedParenthesisquantity = 0;
                        int commaIndex = -1;
                        for (int j = endIndex+1 ; j < function.length() ; j++) {
                            if (function.substring(j,j+1).equals("(")) {
                                openedParenthesisquantity++;
                            }else if (function.substring(j,j+1).equals(")")) {
                                openedParenthesisquantity--;
                                if (openedParenthesisquantity == 0) {
                                    closeParenthesisIndex = j;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }else if (function.substring(j,j+1).equals(",") & openedParenthesisquantity == 0) {
                                if (commaIndex == -1) {
                                    commaIndex = j;
                                }else{
                                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The argument of math function (which is "+alphabeticElement+") has too many commas");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (closeParenthesisIndex == -1) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The argument of a Math function (which is "+alphabeticElement+") hasn't got the closing bracket )");
                        }   
                        String functionArgument = function.substring(endIndex+2,closeParenthesisIndex);
                        if (commaIndex != -1) {
                            double firstParameter = solveComplexFunction(functionArgument.substring(0,commaIndex),motherFunction,values);
                            double secondParameter = solveComplexFunction(functionArgument.substring(commaIndex+1),motherFunction,values);
                            Method mathMethod = Math.class.getDeclaredMethod(alphabeticElement, new Class<?>[] {double.class, double.class});
                            mathMethod.setAccessible(true);
                            String newKey = getNewKey(values);
                            values.put(newKey, (Double) mathMethod.invoke(null, firstParameter, secondParameter));
                            function = function.substring(0, position)+newKey
                                       +((closeParenthesisIndex == function.length()-1)?(""):(function.substring(closeParenthesisIndex+1)));
                        }else {
                            double firstParameter = solveComplexFunction(functionArgument, motherFunction, values);
                            Method mathMethod = Math.class.getDeclaredMethod(alphabeticElement, new Class<?>[] {double.class});
                            mathMethod.setAccessible(true);
                            String newKey = getNewKey(values);
                            values.put(newKey, (Double) mathMethod.invoke(null, firstParameter));
                            function = function.substring(0, position)+newKey
                                       +((closeParenthesisIndex == function.length()-1)?(""):(function.substring(closeParenthesisIndex+1)));
                        }   
                    }else if (!values.containsKey(alphabeticElement)) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found a group of letters ("+alphabeticElement+") which is neither a variable nor a Math function: ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        position++;
    }
    return solveBracketsFunction(function,motherFunction,values);
}

private static double solveBracketsFunction (String function,String motherFunction,HashMap<String, Double> values) throws IllegalArgumentException{

    function = function.replace(" ", "");
    String openingBrackets = "([{";
    String closingBrackets = ")]}";
    int parenthesisIndex = 0;
    do {
        int position = 0;
        int openParenthesisBlockIndex = -1;
        String currentOpeningBracket = openingBrackets.charAt(parenthesisIndex)+"";
        String currentClosingBracket = closingBrackets.charAt(parenthesisIndex)+"";
        if (contOccouranceIn(currentOpeningBracket,function) != contOccouranceIn(currentClosingBracket,function)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: brackets are misused in the function "+function);
        }
        while (position < function.length()) {
            if (function.substring(position,position+1).equals(currentOpeningBracket)) {
                if (position != 0 && !operators.contains(function.substring(position-1,position))) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in function: there must be an operator following a "+currentClosingBracket+" breacket");
                }
                openParenthesisBlockIndex = position;
            }else if (function.substring(position,position+1).equals(currentClosingBracket)) {
                if (position != function.length()-1 && !operators.contains(function.substring(position+1,position+2))) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in function: there must be an operator before a "+currentClosingBracket+" breacket");
                }
                String newKey = getNewKey(values);
                values.put(newKey, solveBracketsFunction(function.substring(openParenthesisBlockIndex+1,position),motherFunction, values));
                function = function.substring(0,openParenthesisBlockIndex)+newKey
                           +((position == function.length()-1)?(""):(function.substring(position+1)));
                position = -1;
            }
            position++;
        }
        parenthesisIndex++;
    }while (parenthesisIndex < openingBrackets.length());
    return solveBasicFunction(function,motherFunction, values);
}

private static double solveBasicFunction (String function, String motherFunction, HashMap<String, Double> values) throws IllegalArgumentException{

    if (!firstContainsOnlySecond(function, alphanumeric+operators)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The function "+function+" is not a basic function");
    }
    if (function.contains("**") |
        function.contains("//") |
        function.contains("--") |
        function.contains("+*") |
        function.contains("+/") |
        function.contains("-*") |
        function.contains("-/")) {
        /*
         * ( -+ , +- , *- , *+ , /- , /+ )> Those values are admitted
         */
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operators are misused in the function");
    }
    function = function.replace(" ", "");
    int position;
    int operatorIndex = 0;
    String currentOperator;
    do {
        currentOperator = operators.substring(operatorIndex,operatorIndex+1);
        if (currentOperator.equals("*")) {
            currentOperator+="/";
            operatorIndex++;
        }else if (currentOperator.equals("+")) {
            currentOperator+="-";
            operatorIndex++;
        }
        operatorIndex++;
        position = 0;
        while (position < function.length()) {
            if ((position == 0 && !(""+function.charAt(position)).equals("-") && !(""+function.charAt(position)).equals("+") && operators.contains(""+function.charAt(position))) ||
                (position == function.length()-1 && operators.contains(""+function.charAt(position)))){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operators are misused in the function");
            }
            if (currentOperator.contains(function.substring(position, position+1)) & position != 0) {
                int firstTermBeginIndex = position;
                while (firstTermBeginIndex > 0) {
                    if ((alphanumeric.contains(""+function.charAt(firstTermBeginIndex))) & (operators.contains(""+function.charAt(firstTermBeginIndex-1)))){
                        break;
                    }
                    firstTermBeginIndex--;
                }
                if (firstTermBeginIndex != 0 && (function.charAt(firstTermBeginIndex-1) == '-' | function.charAt(firstTermBeginIndex-1) == '+')) {
                    if (firstTermBeginIndex == 1) {
                        firstTermBeginIndex--;
                    }else if (operators.contains(""+(function.charAt(firstTermBeginIndex-2)))){
                        firstTermBeginIndex--;
                    }
                }
                String firstTerm = function.substring(firstTermBeginIndex,position);
                int secondTermLastIndex = position;
                while (secondTermLastIndex < function.length()-1) {
                    if ((alphanumeric.contains(""+function.charAt(secondTermLastIndex))) & (operators.contains(""+function.charAt(secondTermLastIndex+1)))) {
                        break;
                    }
                    secondTermLastIndex++;
                }
                String secondTerm = function.substring(position+1,secondTermLastIndex+1);
                double result;
                switch (function.substring(position,position+1)) {
                    case "*": result = solveSingleValue(firstTerm,values)*solveSingleValue(secondTerm,values); break;
                    case "/": result = solveSingleValue(firstTerm,values)/solveSingleValue(secondTerm,values); break;
                    case "+": result = solveSingleValue(firstTerm,values)+solveSingleValue(secondTerm,values); break;
                    case "-": result = solveSingleValue(firstTerm,values)-solveSingleValue(secondTerm,values); break;
                    case "^": result = Math.pow(solveSingleValue(firstTerm,values),solveSingleValue(secondTerm,values)); break;
                    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator: "+currentOperator);
                }
                String newAttribute = getNewKey(values);
                values.put(newAttribute, result);
                function = function.substring(0,firstTermBeginIndex)+newAttribute+function.substring(secondTermLastIndex+1,function.length());
                deleteValueIfPossible(firstTerm, values, motherFunction);
                deleteValueIfPossible(secondTerm, values, motherFunction);
                position = -1;
            }
            position++;
        }
    }while (operatorIndex < operators.length());
    return solveSingleValue(function, values);
}

private static double solveSingleValue (String singleValue, HashMap<String, Double> values) throws IllegalArgumentException{

    if (isDouble(singleValue)) {
        return Double.parseDouble(singleValue);
    }else if (firstContainsOnlySecond(singleValue, alphabetic)){
        return getValueFromVariable(singleValue, values);
    }else if (firstContainsOnlySecond(singleValue, alphanumeric+"-+")) {
        String[] composition = splitByLettersAndNumbers(singleValue);
        if (composition.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong expression: "+singleValue);
        }else {
            if (composition[0].equals("-")) {
                composition[0] = "-1";
            }else if (composition[1].equals("-")) {
                composition[1] = "-1";
            }else if (composition[0].equals("+")) {
                composition[0] = "+1";
            }else if (composition[1].equals("+")) {
                composition[1] = "+1";
            }
            if (isDouble(composition[0])) {
                return Double.parseDouble(composition[0])*getValueFromVariable(composition[1], values);
            }else if (isDouble(composition[1])){
                return Double.parseDouble(composition[1])*getValueFromVariable(composition[0], values);
            }else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong expression: "+singleValue);
            }
        }
    }else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong expression: "+singleValue);
    }
}

private static double getValueFromVariable (String variable, HashMap<String, Double> values) throws IllegalArgumentException{

    Double val = values.get(variable);
    if (val == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown variable: "+variable);
    }else {
        return val;
    }
}

/*
 * FunctionSolver help tools:
 * 
 */

private static final String alphabetic = "abcdefghilmnopqrstuvzwykxy";
private static final String numeric = "0123456789.";
private static final String alphanumeric = alphabetic+numeric;
private static final String operators = "^*/+-"; //--> Operators order in important!

private static boolean firstContainsOnlySecond(String firstString, String secondString) {

    for (int j = 0 ; j < firstString.length() ; j++) {
        if (!secondString.contains(firstString.substring(j, j+1))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static String getNewKey (HashMap<String, Double> hashMap) {

    String alpha = "abcdefghilmnopqrstuvzyjkx";
    for (int j = 0 ; j < alpha.length() ; j++) {
        String k = alpha.substring(j,j+1);
        if (!hashMap.containsKey(k) & !Arrays.asList(usableMathMethods()).contains(k)) {
            return k;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0 ; j < alpha.length() ; j++) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < alpha.length() ; i++) {
            String k = alpha.substring(j,j+1)+alpha.substring(i,i+1);
            if (!hashMap.containsKey(k) & !Arrays.asList(usableMathMethods()).contains(k)) {
                return k;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new NullPointerException();
}

public static String[] usableMathMethods () {

    /*
     *  Only methods that:
     *  return a double type
     *  present one or two parameters (which are double type)
     */

    Method[] mathMethods = Math.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    ArrayList<String> usableMethodsNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Method method : mathMethods) {
        boolean usable = true;
        int argumentsCounter = 0;
        Class<?>[] methodParametersTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        for (Class<?> parameter : methodParametersTypes) {
            if (!parameter.getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("double")) {
                usable = false;
                break;
            }else {
                argumentsCounter++;
            }
        }
        if (!method.getReturnType().getSimpleName().toLowerCase().equals("double")) {
            usable = false;
        }
        if (usable & argumentsCounter<=2) {
            usableMethodsNames.add(method.getName());
        }
    }
    return usableMethodsNames.toArray(new String[usableMethodsNames.size()]);
}

private static boolean isDouble (String number) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(number);
        return true;
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

private static String[] splitByLettersAndNumbers (String val) {
    if (!firstContainsOnlySecond(val, alphanumeric+"+-")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong passed value: <<"+val+">>");
    }
    ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<>();
    String searchingFor;
    int lastIndex = 0;
    if (firstContainsOnlySecond(""+val.charAt(0), numeric+"+-")) {
        searchingFor = alphabetic;
    }else {
        searchingFor = numeric+"+-";
    }
    for (int j = 0 ; j < val.length() ; j++) {
        if (searchingFor.contains(val.charAt(j)+"")) {
            response.add(val.substring(lastIndex, j));
            lastIndex = j;
            if (searchingFor.equals(numeric+"+-")) {
                searchingFor = alphabetic;
            }else {
                searchingFor = numeric+"+-";
            }
        }
    }
    response.add(val.substring(lastIndex,val.length()));
    return response.toArray(new String[response.size()]);
}

private static void deleteValueIfPossible (String val, HashMap<String, Double> values, String function) {
    if (values.get(val) != null & function != null) {
        if (!function.contains(val)) {
            values.remove(val);
        }
    }
}

private static int contOccouranceIn (String howManyOfThatString, String inThatString) {
    return inThatString.length() - inThatString.replace(howManyOfThatString, "").length();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Writing your own library is not that hard as u might thing. Here is link for [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) with step by step algorithm explenation. Although, you will have to parse the input for tokens first.

There are 2 other questions wich can give you some information too: 
[Turn a String into a Math Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084984/turn-a-string-into-a-math-expression)
[What's a good library for parsing mathematical expressions in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226863/whats-a-good-library-for-parsing-mathematical-expressions-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

As there are many answers, I'm adding my implementation on top of `eval()` method with some additional features like support for factorial, evaluating complex expressions etc.

```
package evaluation;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class EvalPlus {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This Evaluation is based on BODMAS rule\n");
        evaluate();
    }

    private static void evaluate() {
        StringBuilder finalStr = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("Enter an expression to evaluate:");
        String expr = scanner.nextLine(); 
        if(isProperExpression(expr)) {
            expr = replaceBefore(expr);
            char[] temp = expr.toCharArray();
            String operators = "(+-*/%)";
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                if((i == 0 && temp[i] != '*') || (i == temp.length-1 && temp[i] != '*' && temp[i] != '!')) {
                    finalStr.append(temp[i]);
                } else if((i > 0 && i < temp.length -1) || (i==temp.length-1 && temp[i] == '!')) {
                    if(temp[i] == '!') {
                        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                        for(int k = i-1; k >= 0; k--) {
                            if(Character.isDigit(temp[k])) {
                                str.insert(0, temp[k] );
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        Long prev = Long.valueOf(str.toString());
                        BigInteger val = new BigInteger("1");
                        for(Long j = prev; j > 1; j--) {
                            val = val.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
                        }
                        finalStr.setLength(finalStr.length() - str.length());
                        finalStr.append("(" + val + ")");
                        if(temp.length > i+1) {
                            char next = temp[i+1];
                            if(operators.indexOf(next) == -1) { 
                                finalStr.append("*");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        finalStr.append(temp[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            expr = finalStr.toString();
            if(expr != null && !expr.isEmpty()) {
                ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
                ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
                try {
                    System.out.println("Result: " + engine.eval(expr));
                    evaluate();
                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please give an expression");
                evaluate();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a valid expression");
            evaluate();
        }
    }

    private static String replaceBefore(String expr) {
        expr = expr.replace("(", "*(");
        expr = expr.replace("+*", "+").replace("-*", "-").replace("**", "*").replace("/*", "/").replace("%*", "%");
        return expr;
    }

    private static boolean isProperExpression(String expr) {
        expr = expr.replaceAll("[^()]", "");
        char[] arr = expr.toCharArray();
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        int i =0;
        while(i < arr.length) {
            try {
                if(arr[i] == '(') {
                    stack.push(arr[i]);
                } else {
                    stack.pop();
                }
            } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
                stack.push(arr[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Please find the updated gist anytime [here](https://gist.github.com/saytosiddiq/3574871abae20995741f33085fe8d2a4). Also comment if any issues are there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some perfectly capable answers here. However for non-trivial script it may be desirable to retain the code in a cache, or for debugging purposes, or even to have dynamically self-updating code.

To that end, sometimes it's [simpler or more robust to interact with Java via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467307/how-to-get-java-getruntime-exec-to-run-a-command-line-program-with-arguments). [Create a temporary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java), [output your script](https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file) and any assets, [create the jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). Finally [import your new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-to-load-jar-files-dynamically-at-runtime).

It's a bit beyond the scope of normal `eval()` use in most languages, though you could certainly implement eval by returning the result from some function in your jar.

Still, thought I'd mention this method as it does fully encapsulate everything Java can do without 3rd party tools, in case of desperation. This method allows me to turn HTML templates into objects and save them, avoiding the need to parse a template at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  strng = "8*-2*3*-1*10/2+6-2";
        String[] oparator = {"+","-","*","/"};
        List<String> op1 = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] x = strng.split("");

        int sayac=0;
        for (String i : x) {
            sayac ++;
            for (String c : oparator) {
                if (i.equals(c)) {

                   try {
                       int j = Integer.parseInt(strng.substring(0, sayac - 1));
                       op1.add(strng.substring(0, sayac - 1));
                       op1.add(c);
                       strng = strng.substring(sayac);
                       sayac = 0;
                   }catch (Exception e)
                   {
                       continue;
                   }
                }

            }
        }
        op1.add(strng);

        ListIterator<String> it = op1.listIterator();
        List<List> newlist = new ArrayList<>() ;

        while (it.hasNext()) {

            List<String> p= new ArrayList<>();
            p.add(String.valueOf(it.nextIndex()));
            p.add(it.next());
            newlist.add(p);

        }

        int sayac2=0;
        String oparatorvalue = "*";
        calculate(sayac2,newlist,oparatorvalue);
        String oparatorvalue2 = "/";
        calculate(sayac2,newlist,oparatorvalue2);
        String oparatorvalue3 = "+";
        calculate(sayac2,newlist,oparatorvalue3);
        String oparatorvalue4 = "-";
        calculate(sayac2,newlist,oparatorvalue4);
        System.out.println("Result:"+newlist.get(0).get(1));


    }


    private static void calculate(int sayac2, List<List> newlist, String oparatorvalue) {
        while (sayac2<4){
            try{
                for (List j : newlist) {
                    if (j.get(1) == oparatorvalue) {
                        Integer opindex = newlist.indexOf(j);
                        Object sayi1 = newlist.get(opindex - 1).get(1);
                        Object sayi2 = newlist.get(opindex + 1).get(1);
                        int sonuc=0;
                        if (oparatorvalue.equals("*")){

                         sonuc = Integer.parseInt(sayi1.toString()) * Integer.parseInt(sayi2.toString());
                        }
                        if (oparatorvalue.equals("/")){

                            sonuc = Integer.parseInt(sayi1.toString()) / Integer.parseInt(sayi2.toString());
                        }
                        if (oparatorvalue.equals("+")){

                            sonuc = Integer.parseInt(sayi1.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(sayi2.toString());
                        }
                        if (oparatorvalue.equals("-")){

                            sonuc = Integer.parseInt(sayi1.toString()) - Integer.parseInt(sayi2.toString());
                        }
                        newlist.remove(opindex - 1);
                        newlist.remove(opindex - 1);
                        newlist.remove(opindex - 1);
                        List<String> sonuclist = new ArrayList<>();
                        sonuclist.add(String.valueOf(opindex - 1));
                        sonuclist.add(String.valueOf(sonuc));
                        newlist.add(opindex - 1, sonuclist);
                    }}}
            catch (Exception e){
                continue;
            }
            sayac2++;}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to import heavy scripting library, you can use [SimpleExpressionEvaluator](https://github.com/vkvashistha/SimpleExpressionEvaluator/blob/main/src/main/java/com/geofriend/expressionevaluator/Expression.java) directly into your code

Usage:

```
Expression.eval("1+2").asString(); // returns "3.0"
Expression.eval("1+2").asInt(); // returns 3
Expression.eval("2>3").asString(); // returns "false"
Expression.eval("2>3").asBoolean(); // returns false
Expression.eval("(3>2)||((2<4)&&(2>1))").asString(); // returns "true"
```

With variables:

```
HashMap<String, Object> st = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
st.put("a",1);  
st.put("b",2);  
st.put("c",3);  
st.put("d",4);  
Expression.eval("a+b", st).asInt();  // or simply asString()
Expression.eval("a>b",st).asBoolean();  // or simply asString()
Expression.eval("(c>b)||((b<d)&&(b>a))",st).asBoolean();  // or simply asString()
Expression.eval("(c>2)||((2<d)&&(b>1))",st).asBoolean();  // or simply asString()
```

Using ExpressionBuilder:

```
Expression.expressionBuilder().putSymbol("a",2).putSymbol("b",3).build("(b>a)").evaluate()
```

Answer (score -5):

The following resolved the issue:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String str = "4*5";
System.out.println(engine.eval(str));
```

Comment: This is virtually identical to the accepted answer.  It is redundant.